# Best Cypress way to check if a tab has become 'active`?

Tags: cypress

Try to do a simple test on the new UI page. It has 2 tabs: `tab-pay`  and `tab-vaca`.
I could use `cy.get(li:tab-vaca').focus()`  to get to this tab.  How can I verify (assert) it's been in in active state then?   And if possible, can I switch by `toggle` to one other tabs later?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the html dom for both when the tab is active and tab is in disabled state ?

Comment: It's like this: `<div class='tabMenu'>  <ul class=tabList> <li tab-pay> <li tab-vaca> </ul>`     Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is for the active tab. How does the disabled tab look like. Is there any class name or attribute being added when the tab is disabled ?

Comment: I double `inspect` them - one shown - `button.tab.tab-inactive`, the other shown `button.tab.tab-active`

Comment: Thats great! Can you post the screenshot for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229636/discussion-between-daniel-hao-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that the tab is diabled:

```
cy.get('li#tab-race > button').should('have.class', 'tab tab-inactive')
```

To go to either tabs:

```
cy.get('ul li').first().click() //go to gender tab
cy.get('ul li').next().click() //go to race tab
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this answer is what if the class name changes? How about checking for a `test-tab-inactive` instead of `tab-inactive`? This would ensure that whoever changes the class knows that it's being used for testing.